# Duplicate feature and origin branch. How to merge?

Tags: git

I am not experienced with git and I created a feature branch called "DTAI" and a accidentally I created a remote branch called  "origin/DTAI" . But I only want the feature branch, not the origin one. Can someone help me on how to merge them or anyway remove the duplicate one, without doing anything stupid to the master branch? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd remove origin/DTAI before puching my local DTAI branch.

Comment: How did you "accidentally" create the remote ref `origin/DTA`?  What makes you think you don't need it?\

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the origin/DTAI without problems if all you code is in DTAI

> without doing anything stupid to the master branch

I would recommend to protect your master branch if possible, that's at least possible on Github and Bitbucket.

Comment: Ok but how to remove the origin/DTAI? Also, whenever I checkout from master to DTAI i get this message " Switched to branch 'DTAI-61'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/DTAI-61'.". So, if i remove the DTAI, won't it cause any troubles?

Comment: For clarity, 'Your branch is up to date with origin/DTAI-61' is Git's way of telling you your most recent local commit matches the most recent remote commit.  In otherwords, the two branches are sync'd.  Removing the upstream branch won't cause any problems.  I tend to think of published topic branches as a backup of what I'm working on locally.  In fact, I sync them often throughout the day.